# How do you get up to this area in the Fornis Region of Xenoblade 3?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Note: I'm not talking about the location that allows you to spend Nopon coins in the Dannagh dessert. There's a seemingly large area of cliff in the middle of Colony 4, Ribbi Flats and Dannagh Dessert that looks like it should be accessible, but I can't find any way up to it. There are containers and husks there too.

Is there a way up? Please don't provide any major spoilers beyond chapter 3 - if access is locked to a certain chapter, quest or traversal skill then that's fine to say so.

[image]

Comment: In case it's not clear from the map, the icon closest to the cursor (going south-east from the cursor) is the location where you can trade Nopon coins.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the area I'm thinking of then I believe you need the climbing traversal skill that lets you climb the purple vines/flowers, you unlock it as you progress through Chapter 3.

The vines you need to climb are in the area above your cursor, on the cliffs behind the colony. You can get to these cliffs by climbing up a sandy slope near the landmark on the top right of your picture. You might need the Scree Walking traversal skill too, but I think you probably have that already judging by where on the map you have uncovered. If not you should be able to unlock it around that point in the story.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question. You mention you need the skill to climb vines, but not how to access the area the OP is asking about

Comment: @Wondercricket fair point, I'll edit it in.